# Can TeamViewer be considered a VPN client?

Tags: vpn

Sorry if the question seems wired, I am far from being a professional server admin: Can we consider TeamViewer a VPN client?

Because if a VPN is the private virtual network of some faction (a personal user or a company) and relevant people can login to that VPN with a VPN client software, than, what is the differnce between a program like TeamViewer to any well-declared VPN client? It also serves as gate to the "**Proxy**" which is the otherside's private-network...

It actually seems to me that TeamViewer serves as both a VPN host and a VPN client, both in one program... Maybe I am missing something heavy here?

Please comment at start if you think I'd better off delete that question.

Comment: Sorry but the question is off-topic and opinionated for Pro Webmasters.

Comment: Simon@ **This community is not all about good question, we may be get good information on silly question as well.**

Comment: @SimonHayter this is definitely **not** opinionated. There are fundamental technical differences between the two technologies. Perhaps it's off-topic but the answer to the question exists and is very clear.

Comment: Goyllo, I suggest you would delete you comment. The question is quite technical and no one must answer and off course, no mod need to accept it. The main reason for me to ask it here was to learn and give knowledge at the same time...

Comment: In some cases, it can be considered a Remote Access Trojan if your security has been compromised. At best, it's synonymous with Microsoft RDP or VNC terminal access. VPN? Never.

Answer (score 1):

No, TeamViewer is a **Remote desktop application**, not a VPN.

Main differences:

- TeamViewer only allows you to take control of a single computer environment at once.
- in contrast to TeamViewer, a VPN allows you to create a secure connection *between a computer and a remote network*, allowing access to remote resources as if you were inside that same physical remote network, thus frequently used by remote workers to log in the corporate network.

Conversely, if you use a VPN you don't automatically have access to a specific user's machine; If you want to access data stored on a computer's hard drive (like you would do using TeamViewer) you cannot automatically do this with a VPN, unless this machine is using shared folders to share content on the network.

Comment: @Benia Hi, I have added some clarifications, please let me know if I can improve it further.

Comment: @Benia done, does it make more sense now?